# Use of var in linq

Tags: linq, anonymous-types

What does `var` really do in the following case?

```
var productInfos =
from p in products
select new { p.ProductName, p.Category, Price = p.UnitPrice };
```

Comment: var is variable which doesn't  have any datatype. you can store anything in var variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`var` is a placeholder for a compiler-created [("anonymous") type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) that has three properties, `ProductName`, `Category` and `Price`.

It is NOT a variant (e.g. as in Visual Basic).  It is a concrete type and can be used as such in other places in the code.

Answer (score 9):

The two lines:

```
var productInfos = from p in products 
select new { p.ProductName, p.Category, Price = p.UnitPrice };
```

and

```
IEnumerable<CompilerGeneratedType> productInfos = from p in products 
select new { p.ProductName, p.Category, Price = p.UnitPrice };
```

are equivalent.  `CompilerGeneratedType` is a type that will be created by the compiler and has the three public properties `ProductName, Price, and Category`.  `var` is helpful for two reasons:

1. `CompilerGeneratedType` will be generated by the compiler so it's impossible for you to use the type name in the declaration.
2. You don't have to think too hard about the collection type of the result.  Linq can do its thing and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: That's a good answer, but not 100% correct.  It's quite possible to refer to the CompilerGeneratedType.  Not directly by name, but certainly indirectly.  For example: var test = new { P1="Hello", P2="Bye" }; Type t = test.GetType(); yields a concrete type with a concrete name, in my concrete example case UnderlyingSystemType: {<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.String]}.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, the type of productInfos is a compiler-generated [Anonymous Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) with 3 properties, ProductName, Category and Price.

Answer (score 3):

variables with var are implicitly typed local variable which are strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type. it gets the type of the result.

and here a nice read [C# Debate: When Should You Use var?](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/05/CSharp-var)

and here another [C# 3.0 Tutorial](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/CSharp3-1)

Answer (score 2):

var = programmer friendly = less typing = makes you lazy(another way of looking at it) = brings obscurity to code if new to 3.5 FW

Answer (score 0):

It eases you from the pain of having to declare the exact type of your query result manually. But I have to empathize, this is not dynamic typing: the `productInfos` variable will have a static type, but it is created by the compiler instead of you.